# display lon and lat of current selected CRS in Map Tip

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, maptips

I would like to set Map Tips to display coordinates of some feature in custom selected CRS. When I do:

```
<b>X: </b>[% $x %]<br>
<b>Y: </b>[% $y %]
```

Tip displays coordinates in WGS84, but not in my current canvas CRS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$x` and `$y` takes coordinates directly from your data geometry (your data are in WGS), so it is project-independent. Probably you have set other CRS with on the fly reprojection, which could confuse you.

If you want display coordinates from data in other CRS, you have to use `transform` function like this:

```
<b>X: </b>[% x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:XXXX')) %]<br>
<b>Y: </b>[% y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:XXXX')) %]
```